# Extract index of a exact match string

Tags: string, r, match

I tried this but this will again required a `for`-loop to compare so any better method to find the index.

```
str[[1]][1]  
"NYA.FWD.AMGM.MON..MAXRUNALARM."
m<-grep( str[[1]][1] , colnames(log_data)[2:ncol(log_data)] , value=FALSE)
m
[1] 5 6
```

where

```
colnames(log_data)[6]
"NYA.FWD.AMGM.MON..MAXRUNALARM....SU."
colnames(log_data)[7]
"NYA.FWD.AMGM.MON..MAXRUNALARM."
```

I only want the **6** as indices ,means the **exact length** of the string or is there an better method to extract the similar string of same length.

I also used

```
str_detect((colnames(log_data)[2:ncol(log_data)]),fixed(str[[1]][1]))
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  **TRUE  TRUE** FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

but getting the logical vectors just want a **single index** ,thank you.

Comment: thanks Jibler for editing it so nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an exact match, use `match`:

```
match(str[[1]][1], colnames(log_data)[2:ncol(log_data)])
```

It will return the index of the first match. If you have multiple matches and want all their indices, do:

```
which(str[[1]][1] == colnames(log_data)[2:ncol(log_data)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regular expression method that uses string length (`nchar` and/or `nzchar`) to return the index for all exact matches.  For the first match only, just append `[1]` to the end of the `which(...)` call below (i.e. `which(...)[1]`).

Assume `c.names` would be the result from `colnames(log_data)`.

```
> s <- "NYA.FWD.AMGM.MON..MAXRUNALARM."
> c.names <- c("NYA.FWD.AMGM.MON..MAXRUNALARM....SU.", 
               "NYA.FWD.AMGM.MON..MAXRUNALARM.",
               "NYA.FWD.AMGM.MON..MAXRUNALARM..D.",
               "..NYA.FWD.AMGM.MON..MAXRUNALARM.",
               "NYA.FWD.AMGM.MON..MAXRUNALARM.")
```

**First match only:**

```
> which(!nzchar(gsub(s, '', c.names)))[1]
## [1] 2
```

**All matches:**

```
> which(!nzchar(gsub(s, '', c.names)))
## [1] 2 5
```